# SUM two colmuns and find highest

Tags: mysql

I want to SUM two columns from two different database and output the highest value.

trying to figure it out since last 1day but no luck. can anyone please help?

```
Table 1    
mid points    
 1 20  
 2 10 
 1 10 
 1 30
 3 10

Table 2    
mid points    
 1 20    
 2 10
 1 10
 2 20
 1 10
 3 10
```

so the total for mid 1 = 100 & 2 = 40 & 3 = 20

output that i want highest total mid is  1 = 100

Comment: So once you've figured out which two columns you're talking about, see normalization.

Comment: @jpw Also if the id repeats and i have to sum each column and then join and output the highest. is it possible?

Comment: Good. Now see normalization. And PRIMARY KEYs too.

Comment: @jpw sum(b1+b2+b3) where id =1 and sum(b4) where id = 1 and join shoud give 120

Comment: no. see table1 1st row where id =1 the sum for b1+b2+b3 = 60 & 3rd row 30.table2 1st row 20 and & 3rd row 10. so total is 120 for id = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description was a bit vague, but as this query is the only that would give the result you describe I guess the query might be what you want. I'm sure it can be done in a smarter way but it should work...

Join the tables and use sum and addition:

```
select t1.id, t1_sum + ifnull(t2_sum,0) as total_sum
from 
    (select id, sum(b1+b2+b3) t1_sum from Table1 group by id) t1 
left join 
    (select id, sum(b4) t2_sum from Table2 group by id) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
order by total_sum desc
limit 1
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65aaf/5)

Comment: @swap They're just table aliases used to shorten the query text. You could remove them after Table1 and Table2 but then you would have to change all t1 to Table1 and t2 to Table2.

Comment: looks like this query will work. but i am not able to output it.

Comment: @swap What do you mean you're not able to output it?

Comment: @jwp I mean how to echo the result

Comment: @jwp please help. I am confused on how to echo the result

Comment: perfect @jwp i got the result but no able to limit it to more than 1

Comment: @swap The last line in the query `limit 1` determines the number of records returned.

Answer (score 0):

A normalised design might look like this...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,bid INT NOT NULL
,b INT NOT NULL
,val INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
( 1  ,1   ,1  ,20),
( 2  ,1   ,2  ,20),
( 3  ,1   ,3  ,20),
( 4  ,2   ,1  ,10),
( 5  ,2   ,2  ,10),
( 6  ,2   ,3  ,30),
( 7  ,1   ,1  ,10),
( 8  ,1   ,2  ,10),
( 9  ,1   ,3  ,10),
(10  ,1   ,4  ,20),
(11  ,2   ,4  ,10),
(12  ,1   ,4  ,10);
```

...at which point querying such a schema becomes trivial...

```
SELECT bid,SUM(val) FROM my_table GROUP BY bid [ORDER BY SUM(val) DESC LIMIT 1];
+-----+----------+
| bid | SUM(val) |
+-----+----------+
|   1 |      120 |
|   2 |       60 |
+-----+----------+
```

Comment: Indeed a much better design